# I can't click on some things and other problems

Tags: 12.04, updates

I have some issues with my Ubuntu 12.04 .

- When I open Ubuntu Software Center, the program opens and than just disappears just when it is opened.
- My Ubuntu 12.04 won't install any updates because of this error in the picture.
- Worst of all: I can't click on anything except for programs that from Ubuntu: for example I can't browse the internet via Firefox or Chromium... I can't click on folders. I can't click on things in my Thunderbird mail program. But I can click on Update manager for example... 
  It is just clicking that doesn't work, when I try 'clicking' something with using the tab-button and enter I can click on something - in every case. But that's just too annoying to do.

Oh sorry guys I had some screenshots that illustrate the problems, but I can't get them off the 'problem pc ubuntu 12.04' about which I am talking... it's so sad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, try to fix Software Center:

1. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> to bring up the Run box
2. Type `bash` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
3. Run this command: `sudo aptitude reinstall software-center`

Although you could run the command right from the Run box, starting bash first lets you see status and error messages from the command.